# Unmanaged RealObject does not persist completely

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a model like this:

```
public class Album extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Required
    private String _id;
    @Required
    private String title;
    private String description;

    public String get_id() {
        return _id;
    }
    public void set_id(String _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

I get the data from a server and convert the JSON to Album object. I try to persist the object into the Realm 3.1.3 in this way:

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.insertOrUpdate(album);
        }
    });
```

But the problem is that the `_id` and `title` fields are copied to the database but the `description` field is always null.
However if I create a new object and copy all of the fields from the original object to the new one, everything persists completely. Here's how it works:

```
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                Album tmpAlbum = new Album();
                tmpAlbum.set_id(album.get_id());
                tmpAlbum.setTitle(album.getTitle());
                tmpAlbum.setDescription(album.getDescription());
                realm.insertOrUpdate(tmpAlbum);
            }
        });
```

Is there another way to persist the whole object without creating a copy from the original object?

Comment: Debug it and check if `album.description` is not null when you trying to save it in realm.

Comment: I checked and `album.description` is not null. When I just copy the value and set it to the `tmpAlbum` object everything is fine.

Comment: Well this can happen only if `description` is null, so....